# STM32-HAL CAN transmits empty error message only

Tags: c++, embedded, microcontroller, can-bus, stm32-hal

I'm trying to transmit messages through CAN using HAL library. For test I repeated code from the first part of [this  video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfWlIY0zAIc) I have the same bluepill so I just did the same. Also I've tried [his project](https://controllerstech.com/can-protocol-in-stm32/), but changing Nucleo RE to ZE model. I've looked through other sources and they all do the same thing, and in their videos/articles bus perfoms as it is supposed to.

But on all of my devices `HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage` produces empty (or maybe error) message

[image]

Theese different lines are TX on one board and RX from other transcievers.

Debugging showed me nothing wrong: function returns `HAL_OK`. I went step by stem through it in debug mode and everything seemed as normal. But niether loopback nor normal mode transmitts correct message.

Also I've checked my LA with MCP2515 + TJA1040 and CAN bus worked as it has to

[image]

So I'm confused and don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in TimeQuanta settings. I had to be more considerate. I'll wrigth a more exact explanation later

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. I had my prescaler set high and my time quanta set to 1 times; I halved my prescaler and set my time quanta to 2, 3, and 2. This solved the problem, not sure why. Copied those numbers from [this tutorial](https://controllerstech.com/can-protocol-in-stm32/)

Comment: "not sure why" – prescaler and time quanta specify time windows in which data is sampled. So if it is set wrong, data will not be sampled correctly

Comment: @lazba What I don't understand is that if I cut my prescaler in half then double the time for each of the time windows, this results in the same bitrate and time periods - why would a different way of getting the same speed and timing result in different behavior?

Comment: CAN hardware samples each bit in exact time windows. When settings are different, sample times and data change times may not align which will result in wrong transmission/reception. You can read more at [this tutorial](http://bittiming.can-wiki.info/)